# osssearchresults.aspx page have problem on handling URL query string

Tags: search, search-results, 2016, sharepoint-search, query-string

I am setting up a SharePoint 2016 on-premise (Enterprise) environment. Right after I setup the first Search Service Application, I create a new site collection with Enterprise search center template. Everything works fine.

However all the existing site collection's `osssearchresults.aspx` page do not work. Any search return 0 result. After investigate, I found it return result after change the query string.

Original string (no result):

```
https://mysharepoint.abc.xyz/sites/abc/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmysharepoint%2Eabc%2Exyz%2Fsites%2Fabc&k=*
```

After remove the `https://` manually from query string(after `?`) it works as expected:

```
https://mysharepoint.abc.xyz/sites/abc/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=mysharepoint%2Eabc%2Exyz%2Fsites%2Fabc&k=*
```

Could you please advise how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if SSL is configured correctly as per below link.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/

Also check if you are passing http:// (without S) in u, does it work?

Definitely it has something to do with your SSL certificate not configured correctly. If you SharePoint admin, please check if SSL is configured correctly as per above link. If you are not SharePoint admin, I would suggest you to involve your SharePoint Infrastrucute team to high light this issue.

Comment: before I raised my question, indeed my SSL is not configured correctly. Nothing but a single error is returned in a full crawl. The error was complaining SSL is not trusted (even I have checked "ignore SSL warning"). I fixed the SSL cert and full crawl again returned about 2000 results.

Comment: I have tried passing http:// (without S) in u, still not work. My environment is configured to accept https only (all AAM are https)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by change the default AAM from "https://servername" to "https://mysharepoint.abc.xyz". The search is working for this string pattern now.

```
https://mysharepoint.abc.xyz/sites/abc/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmysharepoint%2Eabc%2Exyz%2Fsites%2Fabc&k=*
```

However now something else is breaking. When I click my name at right top corner -> mysite it is redirected to "https://servername" instead of "https://mysharepoint.abc.xyz". hmmmm